# При создании объекта с помощью оператора new не срабатывает деструктор

Tags: c++

В этом коде, я присваиваю указателю `current` адрес в памяти, на который указывает указатель, который возвращает функция `listen_port`, и передаю `current` в функцию, где он в последствии используется. Проблема в том, что когда цикл делает следующую итерацию у объекта, на который указывает `current` не вызывается деструктор. Как можно исправить эту проблему ?

```
for(;;)
{
client *current = client::listen_port(cone.get_socket());
httpHandler worker(current);
worker.handle();
}
```

Comment: `delete current;`

Comment: Все объекты, которые вы создаете в куче ( при помощи оператора new)  вам необходимо явно освобождать с помощью delete. 
Решением будет в конце каждой итерации вызывать delete current;

Comment: похоже, то что вы хотите увидеть, реализуется с помощью `std::shared_ptr<client> current = client::listen_port(cone.get_socket());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(;;)
{
    client *current = client::listen_port(cone.get_socket());
    httpHandler worker(current);
    worker.handle();
    delete current;
}
```

Но это работает, если `client::listen_port` создает `client*` через `new`, и если `worker.handle();` не вызывает другой поток, в который оттдает указатель, и если сам `httpHandler` в своем деструкторе не освобождает указатель.